# How to iterate over file names in a R script?

Tags: file, r, for-loop, filenames

A very simple R script adds a ascending row index to a textfile "0.txt" and also adds a header "time" to it. After that the data is written to a file "0-edit.txt"

```
data<-read.table("0.txt", header=TRUE,sep=",",row.names= NULL);
colnames(data)[1] = "time"
write.table(data,quote=FALSE,sep=", ","0-edit.txt");
```

Assume i have 4 files called 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt, ...in the same folder, how can I use a counter (or something else) to iterate over those file names in my script?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
for(i in 0:3) {
  infile <- paste(i,".txt",sep="")
  outfile <- paste(i,"-edit.txt",sep="")

  data <- read.table(infile,header=TRUE,sep=",",row.names=NULL)
  colnames(data)[1] = "time"
  write.table(data,quote=FALSE,sep=", ",outfile)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the paste function escaped me somehow

Comment: @Martin: You're welcome.  You may also find `?file.path` handy.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a solution without a loop using lapply:

```
infiles <- dir(pattern='\\.txt$')

change.files <- function(file){
  data <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names=NULL)
  colnames(data)[1] = "time"
  write.table(data, quote=FALSE, sep=", ", sub("\\.txt$","-edit.txt", file))
}

lapply(infiles , change.files)
```

For me the real advantage of this approach is that you can easily run it in parallel using `mclapply` (from multicore package) instead of lapply. Or `parLapply` from snow. Also to me it looks nicer.

Comment: This just came in handy for another task and I have to agree, it is elegant

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
files <- list.files(path="", pattern=".txt", all.files=T, full.names=T)
for (file in files) {
## do stuff
}
```

You can use regular expressions for the pattern matching, so if you have lots of text files but only want the ones with numeric names, use "[0-9].txt" or "[0-3].txt".

Answer (score 3):

More generally, you can use `dir()` to get the files in a given directory, and use `select` to limit it to .txt files.

```
file.dir <- "/path/to/files"
for(infile in dir(file.dir, pattern="\\.txt$")) {
  outfile <- gsub("\\.txt$","-edit\\.txt", infile)

  data <- read.table(infile,header=TRUE,sep=",",row.names=NULL)
  colnames(data)[1] = "time"
  write.table(data,quote=FALSE,sep=", ",outfile)
}
```