# Automate analysis over multiple .txt files

Tags: r, large-data

I have many copies of two types (a + b) of txt file i.e:

```
a1.txt a2.txt a3.txt... and b1.txt b2.txt b3.txt
```

My aim is to run an r script that does the following:

```
read.table a1.txt
#run a bunch of code that chops and changes the data and then stores some vectors and data      frames.
w<-results
x<-results
detach a1.txt
read.table b1 .txt 
#run a bunch of code that chops and changes the data and then stores some vectors and data frames.
y<-results
z<-results
model1<-lm(w~y)
model2<-lm(x~z)
```

Each time I want to extract coefficients from e.g. 1 slopes for model1 and 2 slopes from model2.
I want to run this analysis in an automated way across all pairs of a and b text files and build up the coefficients in vector format in one other file. for later analysys.

I so far have only been able to get bits and bobs from more simple analyses [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854130/how-to-iterate-over-file-names-in-a-r-script). Does anyone have the best idea on how to run this more complex iteration over many files?

EDIT: Tried so far but failed as yet:

```
your<-function(x) 
{
files <- list.files(pattern=paste('.', x, '\\.txt', sep=''))
a <- read.table(files[1],header=FALSE)
attach(a)
w <- V1-V2
detach(a)
b <- read.table(files[2],header=FALSE)
z <- V1-V2
model <- lm(w~z)
detach(b)
return(model$coefficients[2])
}

slopes <- lapply(1:2, your)
Error in your(1) : object 'V1' not found
```

Comment: 2 things.  First, its best to avoid using `attach` and `detach`.  Second, (would have been avoided by addressing the first!) after you read `b` you don't `attach` it.  Instead use something like `z <- b$V1 - b$V2`.

Comment: I just got that cracked before you got back to me. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
files <- list.files(pattern='.1\\.txt') # get a1.txt and b1.txt
```

if you know how many files you have (lets say 10), you would wrap your code above in a function and use one of the `apply` family depending on your desired output:

```
your.function(x) {
  files <- list.files(pattern=paste('.', x, '\\.txt', sep=''))
  a <- read.table(files[1])
  b <- read.table(files[2])

  w <- ...
  x <- ...

  y <- ...
  z <- ...

  model1 <- lm(w~y)
  model2 <- lm(x~z)

  return(c(model1$coefficients[2], moedl2$coefficients[2]))
}

slopes <- lapply(1:10, your.function)
```

Comment: Hi justin, thanks for your answer, could you possibly clarify the `list.files(pattern=paste('.', x, '\\.txt', sep=''))` section, im unsure about what the `('.', x, '\\.txt', sep='')` arguments take

Comment: `paste` takes an arbitrary number of arguments and smooshes them together with the specified separator (`sep=''` gives no separator).  e.g. `paste('foo', 'bar', sep=' ')` versus `paste('foo', 'bar', sep='!')`.  Does that help?  I'm just mashing the index (the number 1 through 10) onto a regular expression that matches a single character (a or b) plus number.txt (so it should find a1.txt and b1.txt if x=1).  Clear as mud I'm sure!