# Using index or counter to write data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I'm sure this has been asked before, but no luck finding the answer.  If I want to write 10 separate files as part of a loop, how do I go about using the index or counter to increment the name of the files.

```
a <- matrix(5, nrow=5, ncol=5)

for(i in 1:10){
    a <- a + 1
    write.csv(a, "a1.csv") 
}
```

Thus, I would like to extend this code to write 10 files:  a1.csv, a2.csv, a3.csv, and so on.
I'm assuming the answer is straightforward, perhaps using paste0, assign, and [i].  No luck getting it solved!  Of course, if there is a better way to approach this problem without a for loop, I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854130/how-to-iterate-over-file-names-in-a-r-script), just use paste:

```
a <- matrix(5, nrow=5, ncol=5)

for (i in 1:10) {
  a <- a + 1
  write.csv(a, paste("a",i,".csv",sep="")) 
}
```

Comment: `paste0("a", i, ".csv")` is a convenient alternative for the common case when `sep=""`; I prefer `sprintf("a%d.csv", i)`.