# Using a loop to open multple txt files in R

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to use a script in R to open a large number of txt files downloaded from the EDGAR database. The files are doenloaded in mydocuments and are organized in subfolders by the CIK number of each firm and year. Inside each subfolder there are a number of txt files with names like this cik_8-K-year_month_date.txt. I am trying to use a loop in order to open each file and then use the TM package to get the terms I am interested in. The code I am trying to use is the following:

```
for (i in 1:dim(CIK)) {
  for(year in 1980:2017) {
    for (m in 1:12) {
      for (d in 1:30) {
        if(is.na(cik[i])) {
        } else {
          mydata <- read_file("C:\\Documents\\Edgar filings\\as.integer(cik[i])_8-K_year\\as.integer(cik[i])_8-K_year-month[m]-day[d].txt")  
          tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(mydata)
          findAssocs(tdm, c("Chapter 11", "Chapter 7"), c(0.99, 0.99)) 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854130/how-to-iterate-over-file-names-in-a-r-script

Comment: Any help with what?

Comment: Also potentially helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames

Comment: You need to use `paste()` or `sprintf()` to create the path. Also, I'd recommend using `setwd()` to shorten the path that you're referencing in the rest of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over file names in a R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854130/how-to-iterate-over-file-names-in-a-r-script)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
temp <- list()
for(i in 1:length(list.files()))  {
        temp[[i]] <- read_file(file.path(getwd(),list.files()[i])) 
}
```